# How can I set i=index of array before I filter it in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, ngfor, pipes-filters

I am currently having trouble when paginating a list of clients in Angular 2. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let client of eClients | filter:term | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 20, currentPage: p}; let i = index" (click)="toggleClient(i)">
   <td>
    <checkbox [(ngModel)]="eClients[i].selected">
     {{client.name}}
    <checkbox>
   </td>
</tr>
```

The problem is the index is not corresponding to the actual position in the array. For example, if I go to page 2 and click on client #2 in the list I should get an index of 22, however I am getting 2. It seems that the index only spans from 0-19 as I move from page to page. It is filtering the data first and then setting an index. How can I set "i=index" before any of the filters or pagination take place?

P.s. "checkbox" is my own module and "term" is my own pipe filter.

Please help. Thank You

Comment: Maybe it works: `{{ ((p - 1) * itemsPerPage) + i }}` or.. you can use `.map()` and create a property called `index` and store index on each object itself. So, in template you can access `eClients[client.index]`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, neither method worked. First method I am unable to access itemsPerPage or p in the template or when I am making calls to (click)=toggleClient(). Second method worked well for the template but also getting error for the click function when I do (click)=toggleClient(eClients[client.index]). Cannot use client in the function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variable `index` of `*NgFor` is for current result. For your situation, you can get the `original index` by `eClients .indexOf(client)`.

refer [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VRvKSi8xKbiNuiYw6zO4?p=preview).

Comment: Wow, thank you for taking the time to help me with this I really appreciate it! This worked perfectly. I was starting to get ready to change my whole code around.

Answer (score 0):

add fromGroupName for the formArray

```
[formGroupName] = "getFormGroupIndex(i)"
```

for this function compute index:

```
getFormGroupIndex(index: number): number {
   return index + (this.TableCurPage - 1) * this.ItemPerpage;}
```